# Ejecutar un script de Python desde Wordpress

Tags: php, html, python, ajax, wordpress

He creado una página web con Wordpress en la que quiero implementar unos botones que controlen un robot mediante lo que clique el cliente en la web. Tengo el código Python del control del robot y a cada botón html creado le asigno un código php que ejecuta el código python, sin embargo, no lo he logrado aun.
El código html es:

```
<div align="center">
<input type="button" id="script" name="runmyscript" value="▲" onclick="goPython()">
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        function goPython(){
            $.ajax({
              url: "forward.php",
             context: document.body
            }).done(function() {
             alert('finished python script');;
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Y el de php es el siguiente:

```
<? php echo exec("forward.py")?>
```

El codigo de Python es normal, no he añadido nada relacionado con php, ni ajax ni wordpress. Soy bastante primeriza por lo que aun no domino del todo.

¿Tendría que agregar algo en el código de Python con respecto a alguna biblioteca? por favor, ayudadme.

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español

Comment: @BetaM toda la razón, ya esta

Comment: En la versión inglesa de la página, ha sido contestada. Por si te sirve de ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php